# format ‘%ld’ expects type ‘long int’, but argument 3 has type "TEST"

Tags: c, gcc-warning

Here TEST is  a struct pointer. Structure contains integer. What can be the right factor for it? The TEST structure is as follows.I am using gcc as compiler.

```
     typedef struct TEST_HELP{
                 int value;                
      } *TEST, TEST_NODE;
```

Comment: Is this the line of code with the error in your title?  If not, post that too.

Comment: Use `testobj.value` instead of `testobj`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you have something like:

```
TEST ptr;
// set ptr to something
ptr->value = 5;
printf( "%ld", ptr ); // expect 5 to be printed
```

This will not work because `printf` doesn't know how to print a TEST_HELP structure. You need to print the data within it:

```
TEST ptr;
// set ptr to something
ptr->value = 5;
printf( "%ld", (long)ptr->value ); // expect 5 to be printed
```

You should be using `%d` for `int` values. `%ld` is for `long` values, hence the cast.

Comment: Should really be `(long) ptr->value`.

Comment: @Steve: Yes, you're probably right. I was wondering about using %ld for an int rather than %d.